# Converting character to numeric without losing information

Tags: r, character, numeric

I would like to convert below character data to a numeric data. But as.numeric is trimming some information. How can I ensure that I get 1.00000000000000000000000000000001 after converting to numeric?

```
> a="1.00000000000000000000000000000001"
> as.numeric(a)
[1] 1
> as.numeric(a,10)
[1] 1
> as.numeric(as.character(a))
[1] 1
> as.double(a)
[1] 1
```

Comment: This is one of the most-often asked questions on SO.  First of all, you need to learn the difference between a stored value and the displayed precision (which in `R` can be adjusted with things like `options`).  Second, you need to learn about machine precision and how floating-point numbers are stored in binary digital computers.  For example, `a="1.00000000000001"
sprintf('%1.20f',as.numeric(a))
[1] "1.00000000000000999201" `   Third, check out the limit of precision of floating-point values.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to carry that much precision, consider the package `Rmpfr`

```
library(Rmpfr)
longa<-mpfr("1.00000000000000000000000000000001",200)
longa
1 'mpfr' number of precision  200   bits 
[1] 1.0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000004
```

Notice that even here there's a little `4x10-[bignumber]` error.

Try something fancier:

```
mpfr("1.00000000000000000000000000000001e50",200)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  200   bits 
[1] 100000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000 #is an integer, so no error
mpfr("1.00000000000000000000000000000001e50",200)/1e50
1 'mpfr' number of precision  200   bits 
[1] 0.99999999999999992370230158908114578838913309406505827306768701
```

What I'm pointing out is that you need to be really careful when working with floating-point numbers on computers.

Answer (score 2):

It is not a problem with `as.character` but with the limits of the numerical precision:

```
> a <- 1.00000000000000000000000000000001
> a == 1
[1] TRUE
```